# What is the significance of an Azure Resource Group location

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am confused about the Location of resource groups in Azure. As can be seen in the attached Visual Studio dialog, when adding a Function App, I can select a resource group that is nominally located in Western Europe, but select the Israel location for the function app, Azure Storage account and Application Insights.

I was also able to create an sql server in the western europe resource group but with an Israel location.

So what is the meaning (if any) of the location of the resource group?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you create a resource group for a certain location, resources in that resource group can only be created in that region. There might be a few exceptions for Azure managed services which are served from a central location. You should always create a support request to let Microsoft investigate it and provide a fix if needed. The location is Metadata of the resource group, and a resource group is a container of a workload. Unless it's multi region you don't want to have your resources spread across regions. In my experience that metadata is inherented by the resources you create in a resource group.

*Edit
I was wrong within a resource group you can create resources in different regions. But I wouldn't recommend it.
Just to keep it simple and have a good overview. Having resources in a resource group in different regions just creates a mess I think. As a design best practice create resource group in different regions but keep the resources in that resource group in the same region. And if it's one workload or application cobsider the geographical proximity of Azure regions to your users or other services. Choosing a region close to your users can reduce latency, resulting in better performance for applications.(according to the Azure well architected framework*).
When you have users all over the world I would recommend looking into azure front door. Azure front door has a global presence within the Microsoft network and can present the application from a location as close to the user as possible, it can also integrate with a cdn.

Comment: Thank you @Turdie. So you think the facts I record indicate a bug?

Comment: Yes for some strange reason they storage account is also placed in Israel. The location is Metadata of the resource group, and a resource group is a container of a workload. Unless it's multi region you don't want to have your resources spread across regions. Or are you using a template where the location in is specified? Bicep or ARM or Terraform

Comment: That’s not entirely true.  The location of the resource group has no bearing on the location of the resources within it (ignoring Azure Policy/etc.).  All it defines is where the metadata about the RG is stored (usually for regulatory purposes).

Comment: Thanks @GregW. So does the fact the metadata about an RG reside for example in western europe have any performance implications if an SQL server resides in Israel but belongs to that RG?

Comment: @GilShalit nothing at all

Comment: But @GregW,why is that not true? Because when I create a resource group in a certain location, i can't create resources in another region, when i create those resources in that region.

Comment: Can you rephrase that?  I have Resource Groups with resources from separate regions without issue.  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview. “The resources in a resource group can be located in different regions than the resource group.”

Comment: Sorry @GregW you are correct that was a mindfuck of mine. But it's not best practice because it increases latency and so on, you want your resources in terms of location as close as possible together. And if you need to publish it globally use something like front door which has a global presence. I would always recommend to choose one or two locations.

Comment: Consider the geographical proximity of Azure regions to your users or other services. Choosing a region close to your users can reduce latency, resulting in better performance for applications. According to the Azure well architected framework.

Comment: Agreed.  The MS Learn article goes into much more detail on the topic.